# Relative path working with "@import" but not working with "@use"

Tags: angular, sass

I'm migrating from **@import** to **@use** to avoid future deprecation and this statement

```
@import '../versions-cs-theming';
```

Works with @import but not with @use

```
@use '../versions-cs-theming';
---> SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
20 │   height: $ligne-fichier-cs-height;
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

The documentation tells us that the path will be loaded relatively: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#load-paths

> Modules will always be loaded relative to the current file first, though. Load paths will only be used if no relative file exists that matches the module’s URL. This ensures that you can’t accidentally mess up your relative imports when you add a new library.

But even if it says so, that @use doesn't work with this folder structure

```
version
-->version-cs
---->version-cs.component.scss
-->version-cs-theming.scss
```

Knowing that I'm not using `stylePreprocessorOptions`, do you have any idea of what could be the issue?